# Las imágenes de los correos enviados con schedule command no se ven

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo un envió masivo de correos usando schedule command, los correos llegan pero en el cuerpo contienen dos imágenes las cuales no se ven. En cambio si se envía un correo manual si se ve.

Comment: Comparte tu código de la vista que usas en tu correo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolvi cambiando de proveedor de SMTP, lo cambie por Sendgrid.